# call a SOAP web service that doesn't exist

Tags: java, soap, glassfish, soapui, payara

I have deployed a WAR file with SOAP endpoints and created a handler to detect any call for all web services that the client may call. I want to detect the nonexistent web service but unfortunately, I am getting errors on Payara only if I deployed the WAR file on any other application server (glassfish or Tomcat) it works as expected the error has been logged by the handler. Here is an example for request/response using SOAPUi and web services deploy on Payara.

**Request:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.jaxws.demo.jcg/">
soapenv:Header/
soapenv:Body
ser:getBooks

1
</ser:getBooks>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Response:**

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
S:Server
java.lang.NullPointerException
</S:Fault>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**I am getting this error on server.log**

[2023-01-15T16:49:30.029+0300] [Payara 5.2021.7] [SEVERE] [AS-WSSECURITY-00001] [javax.enterprise.webservices.security] [tid: _ThreadID=740 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-2(620)] [timeMillis: 1673790570029] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Request processing failed.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.ArrayDeque.addLast(ArrayDeque.java:249)
at org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.pushWebServiceMethod(InvocationManagerImpl.java:386)
at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.pushWebServiceMethod(MonitoringPipe.java:211)
at org.glassfish.webservices.MonitoringPipe.process(MonitoringPipe.java:132)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1106)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1020)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:989)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:847)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.AbstractTubeImpl.process(AbstractTubeImpl.java:106)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.processRequest(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:195)
at com.sun.enterprise.security.webservices.CommonServerSecurityPipe.process(CommonServerSecurityPipe.java:134)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.helper.PipeAdapter.processRequest(PipeAdapter.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:1106)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:1020)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:989)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:847)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:838)

**The request/response for the same web service deployed on glassfish**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.jaxws.demo.jcg/">
soapenv:Header/
soapenv:Body
ser:getBooks

1
</ser:getBooks>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">SOAP-ENV:Header/<S:Body><S:Fault xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">S:Client
Cannot find dispatch method for {http://service.jaxws/}getfBook
</S:Fault>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```